# How to debug flutter code and native code both in IOS xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter

I am working on an ios project which has both objective c and swift languages. Now there is a need to migrate to Flutter technology for building the same app. So we are trying to integrate the flutter into existing ios project. The main problem here is I cannot debug flutter in xcode. Is there a way to debug and run both ios and flutter in a single frame/tool?